# easyui datagrid header border style

Tags: css, datagrid, header, jquery-easyui

I want to set different border-right for a field in datagrid. I have try this but it's just effected to the row not the header

```
styler: function (value, row, index){
  return 'border-right:2px solid #000;header-border-right:2px solid #000;';
}
```

does anyone try this before? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by add this code on datagrid

```
onLoadSuccess: function (data) {
  var panel = $(this).datagrid("getPanel");
  var myheaderCol = panel.find("div.datagrid-header td[field='quantity']");
  // here is to add the css style
  myheaderCol.css("border-right","2px solid #000");
}
```

hope this can help others who looking for this kind of solution.